# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'O'

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I am relatively new to python, and as such I don't always understand why I get errors. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 43, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'O'
```

This is the line it's referring to:

```
np.insert(arr, [i,num], "O")
```

I'm trying to change a value in a numpy array.

Some code around this line for context:

```
hOne = [one,two,three]
hTwo = [four,five,six]
hThree = [seven, eight, nine]
arr = np.array([hOne, hTwo, hThree])
test = "O"
while a != Answer :
  Answer = input("Please Enter Ready to Start")
if a == Answer:
  while win == 0:
    for lists in arr:
      print(lists)
    place = int(input("Choose a number(Use arabic numerals 1,5 etc.)"))
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
      for num in range(0, len(arr[i])):
        print(arr[i,num], "test")
        print(arr)
        if place == arr[i,num]:
          if arr[i,num]:
            np.delete(arr, [i,num])
            np.insert(arr, [i,num], "O")
            aiTurn = 1
          else:
            print(space_taken)
```

The number variables in the lists just hold the int version of themselves, so one = 1, two = 2 three = 3, etc

I've also tried holding "O" as a variable and changing it that way as well.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you are trying to do here, but are you sure that you want to insert the letter 'O' into your array, not the number '0'?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Yes, I want to insert the letter 'O' into my array, because when I attempt to insert the number '0', it messes with the program. When I try to insert the number '0', it runs without the error, but doesn't replace the variable in the numpy array.

Comment: A numpy array is different from a python list -- you cannot store variables of different types in the same array. The moment you create your array (because all your number variables are numbers), its `dtype` is set to `np.int` or `np.float` (most likely `np.float`), which means that you cannot insert or assign values of any other type to this array. This leaves you with two choices to solve your problem (1) use python lists or (2) don't use 'O' -- you can instead use a value that will never occur otherwise, like `-1` or `np.nan`.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasKühn